# Celdas con bordes redondeados ITEXT7 C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, itextsharp, itext

Estoy leyendo la documentación de ITEXT7 para crear table, pude realizar la tabla pero no logro llegar a poner los bordes redondeados como en este ejemplo.

Donde puedo conseguir  alguna documentación que me pueda guiar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Estuve en el mismo problema durante días; si bien existen las propiedades de las celdas que permiten aplicar este estilo, al compilar no se me visualizaban los cambios. Después de tanto buscar, el problema está en un atributo que se le debe aplicar a la tabla.

Para que aplique correctamente los cambios, tu ejemplo podría quedar así:

```
//1. Crea la tabla.
Table EjemploTable = new Table(3);
EjemploTable.SetBorderCollapse(BorderCollapsePropertyValue.SEPARATE); // importante: este atributo permite aplicar los bordes.
//2. Crea las celdas del encabezado.
Cell Title = new Cell(1,1);
//3. Aplica los estilos.
Title.SetPadding(5); // si deseas aplicar padding
Title.SetBorder(new SolidBorder(ColorConstants.BLACK, 1)); // establece el color y el grosor del borde
Title.SetBorderRadius(new BorderRadius(5));// establece el radio del borde.
Title.SetBackgroundColor(ColorConstants.GREEN);
//Importante para mejores practicas de desarrollo crea una variable local "Style" y luego la agregas con Title.AddStyle(Style), para cada caso sobre todo para el cuerpo ya que dependiendo la celda deberá usar un radio distinto. te dejo ejemplo:
//cell.SetBorderTopLeftRadius(new BorderRadius(Radius));
//cell.SetBorderBottomLeftRadius(new BorderRadius(Radius));
//cell.SetBorderBottomRightRadius(new BorderRadius(Radius));
//cell.SetBorderTopRightRadius(new BorderRadius(Radius));
```